# JavaFX ChoiceDialog CSS

Tags: css, javafx-8

I have a ChoiceDialog in my JavaFX application, and for the life of me can't figure out what CSS elements are required to change the look and feel of it. My other dialog-panes seems to be effected by my external CSS file, so I am guessing it is a element I am not familiar with.

Also, this would be to override the modena css.

I have tried:

```
.dialog-pane {
-fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane .label {
-fx-text-fill: white;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel {
-fx-background-color: black;
}

.dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label {
-fx-font-style: italic;
-fx-font-size: 2em;
}
```

I also tried:

```
.choice-dialog .dialog-pane {
-fx-background-color: black;
}

.choice-dialog .dialog-pane .label {
-fx-text-fill: white;
}

.choice-dialog .dialog-pane:header .header-panel {
-fx-background-color: black;
}

.choice-dialog .dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label {
-fx-font-style: italic;
-fx-font-size: 2em;
}
```

As well as a few other variants of those 2 (.choice-dialog  & .dialog-pane)
Another thing I tried (after looking at the modena.css file) was to change the icon that displays in the ChoiceDialog by doing the following:

from

```
.choice-dialog.dialog-pane {
-fx-graphic: url("dialog-confirm.png");
}
```

to

```
.choice-dialog.dialog-pane {
-fx-graphic: url("dialog-warning.png");
}
```

though this yielded no results either.

**UPDATE**

I updated my custom CSS file, removed it all and retried the css mentioned above. The first block of CSS only changes DialogPane, not a ChoiceDialog. The second and third did nothing at all.

Here is the code I used to create the ChoiceDialog

```
ChoiceDialog<String> dialog = new ChoiceDialog<>("district", choices);
dialog.setTitle("Object Selection");
dialog.setHeaderText("Which object should the file inherit from?");
dialog.setContentText("Default Object:");

Stage dialogStage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
dialogStage.getIcons().add(icon);
dialogStage.initOwner(stage);

Optional<String> response = dialog.showAndWait();
response.ifPresent(chosen ->
{
    //It does something...
});
```

[image: ChoiceDialog]

```
Dialog<ObservableList<DataFilter>> dialog = new Dialog<>();
dialog.getDialogPane().setPrefSize(620, 430);
dialog.setTitle("Field Filter");
dialog.getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(save_bt, cancel_bt);
dialog.initOwner(stage);
dialog.setResultConverter((ButtonType b) ->
{
    if (b == save_bt)
    {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(dataFilters);
    }
    return null;
 });

 Stage stage = (Stage) dialog.getDialogPane().getScene().getWindow();
 stage.getIcons().add(icon);
```

[image: DialogPane]

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail? What style are you trying to apply, and what have you actually tried in order to apply it? Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Updated to show what I tried.

Comment: Have you tried `.choice-dialog.dialog-pane` (as in the snippet you posted from modena.css, without the space), instead of `.choice-dialog .dialog-pane` (with the space)? The `url(...)` function will look for the image file relative to the CSS file, so unless you have one there that snippet will not work. If those fixes don't work, I recommend you post a [MCVE].

Comment: Your first code block changes the background color and text fill just fine for me.

Comment: I updated this again and added both some Java and images to help describe as suggested.

Comment: Note that there are no "elements" in CSS. They are "rules". It is HTML that has elements.

Comment: What is the `-fx-` prefix? I've never seen that and can't find it with Google. Are you serving it with that?

Answer (score 0):

Took me an hour of experiments. A couple of other selectors are in modena.css under "STYLES FOR THE DEFAULT LISTVIEW-BASED COMBOBOX"

```
.dialog-pane{
-fx-background-color: #7160DC;
   }
 .dialog-pane > *.button-bar > *.container{
 -fx-background-color: #7160DC;
  }
  .dialog-pane > .content .label{
  -fx-font-size: 15px;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
   -fx-text-fill: orange;
   }
  .dialog-pane:header .header-panel{
   -fx-background-color: #9589DF;
    }
    .dialog-pane:header .header-panel .label{
    -fx-font-size: 18px;
    -fx-font-style: italic;
     }

   .button{
    -fx-background-color:black;
    -fx-text-fill:white;
    }

  .button:hover{     
  -fx-background-color:orange;
   -fx-text-fill:black;
   -fx-font-weight:bold; 
   }

   /* styles background of cover choice*/
   .combo-box {
  -fx-background-color: black;
  -fx-font-weight: bold;
   }
  /* styles text of cover choice*/
  .combo-box > .list-cell {
  -fx-text-fill: yellow;
  }

 .combo-box-popup > .list-view {
-fx-background-color:black;
-fx-background-insets: 0, 1;
-fx-effect: dropshadow( gaussian , rgba(0,0,0,0.2) , 12, 0.0 , 0 , 8 );
 }

.combo-box-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet >  .list-cell {
-fx-padding: 4 0 4 5;
-fx-background: black;
}

.combo-box-popup > .list-view > .virtual-flow > .clipped-container > .sheet   
> .list-cell:filled:hover {
-fx-background-color: orange;
 -fx-text-fill: black;
 }

 //add the above .css file as stylesheet

ChoiceDialog dialog = new ChoiceDialog();
    dialog.setTitle("Confirmation");
    dialog.setContentText("Some Text");
    DialogPane dp = dialog.getDialogPane();
    dp.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("myCssFile.css")
    .toExternalForm());
    Optional<String> result = dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: What is that? How does it answer the question? What does it do? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: That is a .css file and answers the question "How to style a ChoiceDialog" ? It does styling after adding it as stylesheet to the ChoiceDialog. I'll update the answer with code how to add a stylesheet.

Comment: Not my point. My point is you shouldn't just blurt out markup without explanation. No one learns from that.